# Switch to buffer conditional to no file having been specified in the command line?

Tags: buffers, start-up, command-line-arguments

On startup, I want to create an empty buffer and switch to it, but only if no file has been specified in the command line.

The closest I have is

```
(switch-to-buffer "untitled")
```

at the end of `init.el` but this still creates an "untitled" buffer even when I specify a file in the command line. I don't want this because it slows things down and leaves an unneeded buffer lying around.

Comment: The default \*scratch\* buffer will give you the same functionality. If you launch emacs without specifying a file (and if you don't use `desktop`), the \*scratch\* buffer will be the first buffer you see.

Comment: yes, but the *scratch* buffer is special (can't be deleted), I prefer an ordinary buffer

Comment: By default the scratch buffer can be deleted like any other, so perhaps you've configured something to prevent that. You could also customize `initial-buffer-choice`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *scratch* buffer as an empty buffer, as suggested in the
comments, is a possible solution.

However, if you prefer to leave the *scratch* buffer alone, then this is
an alternative

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda () (when (cl-notany 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))
                       (switch-to-buffer
                        (generate-new-buffer-name "untitled")))))
```

It will create a new "untitled" buffer and will switch to it, but only if
there isn't any buffer that is visiting a file (as would occur when Emacs is started with a filename argument).

Customizing `initial-buffer-choice` didn't work for me, as it creates the buffer unconditionally.

Comment: Ah, I should have tested the `initial-buffer-choice` approach first. :-D It does allow specifying a function so one could presumably use the same conditional logic you've used here -- but the startup hook seems like a logical solution.